# how to grant permissions to the roles in a database on particular tables

Tags: mysql

I have the roles user,employee and admin and i have the table PAYROLE.This table should only modified by user and admin.How to apply this change?

how do i create revoke permissions to employee role on that particular table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short list of other common possible permissions that users can enjoy.

- ALL PRIVILEGES- as we saw previously, this would allow a MySQL user all access to a designated database (or if no database is selected, across the system)
- CREATE- allows them to create new tables or databases
- DROP- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
- DELETE- allows them to delete rows from tables
- INSERT- allows them to insert rows into tables
- SELECT- allows them to use the Select command to read through databases
- UPDATE- allow them to update table rows
- GRANT OPTION- allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges To provide a specific user with a permission, you can use this framework

  GRANT [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;

If you want to give them access to any database or to any table, make sure to put an asterisk (*) in the place of the database name or table name.

Each time you update or change a permission be sure to use the Flush Privileges command.

If you need to revoke a permission, the structure is almost identical to granting it:

```
 REVOKE [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] FROM ‘[username]’@‘localhost’;
```

Comment: here instead of username i want userrole .How can i keep

Comment: you mean to say, you have userrole on your webapp and that you want to use on database ?

Comment: how to implement this kind of db design http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/designing-a-user-authenication-roles-rights-module